# Computing values from textfield in realtime using Dreamweaver

Tags: php, dreamweaver, textfield

I have three text fields which are Quantity, Quantity_per_Unit and Quantity_In_Pieces. How do I populate Quantity_In_Pieces with the product of values from Quantity and Quantity_Per_Unit without having the need to refresh the form? I had no luck in implementing Javascript's textInputEvent.

Comment: you can try on key events for textfields like key up or down

Answer (score 0):

or you can try onchange() and post your values to a function which calculates and write the correct value to the formfileds.